# c99 inline semantics with gcc (mspgcc)

Tags: c, inline, extern

I am writing a couple of functions that I would like to inline.

Reading [here](http://www.greenend.org.uk/rjk/tech/inline.html) and using the second c99 inline option with inline on all declarations and definitions, like so:

```
extern inline void SPFD54124B_write_cmd(uint16_t command);
```

in a header, and

```
inline void SPFD54124B_write_cmd(uint16_t command)
{
    spi_write(command, CMD_WIDTH);
}
```

in a corresponding c file. I was expecting to get inlined versions of the functions.

But when I compile i get:

```
Generating dependencies dep/spi.d from src/spi.c
Generating dependencies dep/spfd54124b.d from src/spfd54124b.c
Generating dependencies dep/pomodoro.d from src/pomodoro.c
Generating dependencies dep/font8x8_ualnum.d from src/font8x8_ualnum.c
Generating dependencies dep/font8x8_basic.d from src/font8x8_basic.c
Generating dependencies dep/evading_util.d from src/evading_util.c
Compiling src/evading_util.c
Compiling src/font8x8_basic.c
Compiling src/font8x8_ualnum.c
Compiling src/pomodoro.c
src/spfd54124b.h:96:20: warning: inline function 'SPFD54124B_write_pixel' declared but never defined [enabled by default]
src/spfd54124b.h:95:20: warning: inline function 'SPFD54124B_write_param' declared but never defined [enabled by default]
src/spfd54124b.h:94:20: warning: inline function 'SPFD54124B_write_cmd' declared but never defined [enabled by default]
src/spi.h:22:20: warning: inline function 'spi_write' declared but never defined [enabled by default]
src/spfd54124b.h:96:20: warning: inline function 'SPFD54124B_write_pixel' declared but never defined [enabled by default]
src/spfd54124b.h:95:20: warning: inline function 'SPFD54124B_write_param' declared but never defined [enabled by default]
src/spfd54124b.h:94:20: warning: inline function 'SPFD54124B_write_cmd' declared but never defined [enabled by default]
src/spi.h:22:20: warning: inline function 'spi_write' declared but never defined [enabled by default]
src/pomodoro.c: In function 'main':
src/spfd54124b.h:94:20: warning: inlining failed in call to 'SPFD54124B_write_cmd': function body not available [-Winline]
src/pomodoro.c:29:25: warning: called from here [-Winline]
src/spfd54124b.h:94:20: warning: inlining failed in call to 'SPFD54124B_write_cmd': function body not available [-Winline]
src/pomodoro.c:31:25: warning: called from here [-Winline]
src/spfd54124b.h:94:20: warning: inlining failed in call to 'SPFD54124B_write_cmd': function body not available [-Winline]
src/pomodoro.c:35:25: warning: called from here [-Winline]
src/spfd54124b.h:94:20: warning: inlining failed in call to 'SPFD54124B_write_cmd': function body not available [-Winline]
src/pomodoro.c:36:25: warning: called from here [-Winline]
src/spfd54124b.h:96:20: warning: inlining failed in call to 'SPFD54124B_write_pixel': function body not available [-Winline]
src/pomodoro.c:40:31: warning: called from here [-Winline]
src/spfd54124b.h:94:20: warning: inlining failed in call to 'SPFD54124B_write_cmd': function body not available [-Winline]
src/pomodoro.c:43:25: warning: called from here [-Winline]
Compiling src/spfd54124b.c
src/spi.h:22:20: warning: inline function 'spi_write' declared but never defined [enabled by default]
src/spi.h:22:20: warning: inline function 'spi_write' declared but never defined [enabled by default]
src/spfd54124b.c: In function 'SPFD54124B_init':
src/spi.h:22:20: warning: inlining failed in call to 'spi_write': function body not available [-Winline]
src/spfd54124b.c:124:14: warning: called from here [-Winline]
src/spi.h:22:20: warning: inlining failed in call to 'spi_write': function body not available [-Winline]
src/spfd54124b.c:129:14: warning: called from here [-Winline]
src/spi.h:22:20: warning: inlining failed in call to 'spi_write': function body not available [-Winline]
src/spfd54124b.c:124:14: warning: called from here [-Winline]
src/spi.h:22:20: warning: inlining failed in call to 'spi_write': function body not available [-Winline]
src/spfd54124b.c:129:14: warning: called from here [-Winline]
src/spfd54124b.c: In function 'SPFD54124B_read':
src/spi.h:22:20: warning: inlining failed in call to 'spi_write': function body not available [-Winline]
src/spfd54124b.c:25:14: warning: called from here [-Winline]
src/spi.h:22:20: warning: inlining failed in call to 'spi_write': function body not available [-Winline]
src/spfd54124b.c:29:14: warning: called from here [-Winline]
src/spfd54124b.c: In function 'SPFD54124B_write_cmd':
src/spi.h:22:20: warning: inlining failed in call to 'spi_write': function body not available [-Winline]
src/spfd54124b.c:124:14: warning: called from here [-Winline]
src/spfd54124b.c: In function 'SPFD54124B_write_param':
src/spi.h:22:20: warning: inlining failed in call to 'spi_write': function body not available [-Winline]
src/spfd54124b.c:129:14: warning: called from here [-Winline]
src/spfd54124b.c: In function 'SPFD54124B_write_pixel':
src/spi.h:22:20: warning: inlining failed in call to 'spi_write': function body not available [-Winline]
src/spfd54124b.c:129:14: warning: called from here [-Winline]
src/spi.h:22:20: warning: inlining failed in call to 'spi_write': function body not available [-Winline]
src/spfd54124b.c:129:14: warning: called from here [-Winline]
src/spfd54124b.c: In function 'SPFD54124B_setrow':
src/spi.h:22:20: warning: inlining failed in call to 'spi_write': function body not available [-Winline]
src/spfd54124b.c:124:14: warning: called from here [-Winline]
src/spi.h:22:20: warning: inlining failed in call to 'spi_write': function body not available [-Winline]
src/spfd54124b.c:129:14: warning: called from here [-Winline]
src/spi.h:22:20: warning: inlining failed in call to 'spi_write': function body not available [-Winline]
src/spfd54124b.c:129:14: warning: called from here [-Winline]
src/spi.h:22:20: warning: inlining failed in call to 'spi_write': function body not available [-Winline]
src/spfd54124b.c:129:14: warning: called from here [-Winline]
src/spi.h:22:20: warning: inlining failed in call to 'spi_write': function body not available [-Winline]
src/spfd54124b.c:129:14: warning: called from here [-Winline]
src/spfd54124b.c: In function 'SPFD54124B_setcol':
src/spi.h:22:20: warning: inlining failed in call to 'spi_write': function body not available [-Winline]
src/spfd54124b.c:124:14: warning: called from here [-Winline]
src/spi.h:22:20: warning: inlining failed in call to 'spi_write': function body not available [-Winline]
src/spfd54124b.c:129:14: warning: called from here [-Winline]
src/spi.h:22:20: warning: inlining failed in call to 'spi_write': function body not available [-Winline]
src/spfd54124b.c:129:14: warning: called from here [-Winline]
src/spi.h:22:20: warning: inlining failed in call to 'spi_write': function body not available [-Winline]
src/spfd54124b.c:129:14: warning: called from here [-Winline]
src/spi.h:22:20: warning: inlining failed in call to 'spi_write': function body not available [-Winline]
src/spfd54124b.c:129:14: warning: called from here [-Winline]
src/spfd54124b.c: In function 'SPFD54124B_lputch':
src/spi.h:22:20: warning: inlining failed in call to 'spi_write': function body not available [-Winline]
src/spfd54124b.c:124:14: warning: called from here [-Winline]
src/spi.h:22:20: warning: inlining failed in call to 'spi_write': function body not available [-Winline]
src/spfd54124b.c:129:14: warning: called from here [-Winline]
src/spi.h:22:20: warning: inlining failed in call to 'spi_write': function body not available [-Winline]
src/spfd54124b.c:129:14: warning: called from here [-Winline]
src/spi.h:22:20: warning: inlining failed in call to 'spi_write': function body not available [-Winline]
src/spfd54124b.c:129:14: warning: called from here [-Winline]
src/spi.h:22:20: warning: inlining failed in call to 'spi_write': function body not available [-Winline]
src/spfd54124b.c:129:14: warning: called from here [-Winline]
src/spfd54124b.c: In function 'SPFD54124B_putch':
src/spi.h:22:20: warning: inlining failed in call to 'spi_write': function body not available [-Winline]
src/spfd54124b.c:124:14: warning: called from here [-Winline]
src/spi.h:22:20: warning: inlining failed in call to 'spi_write': function body not available [-Winline]
src/spfd54124b.c:129:14: warning: called from here [-Winline]
src/spi.h:22:20: warning: inlining failed in call to 'spi_write': function body not available [-Winline]
src/spfd54124b.c:129:14: warning: called from here [-Winline]
src/spi.h:22:20: warning: inlining failed in call to 'spi_write': function body not available [-Winline]
src/spfd54124b.c:129:14: warning: called from here [-Winline]
src/spi.h:22:20: warning: inlining failed in call to 'spi_write': function body not available [-Winline]
src/spfd54124b.c:129:14: warning: called from here [-Winline]
Compiling src/spi.c
Linking bin/pomodoro.elf

>>>> Size of Firmware <<<<
   text    data     bss     dec     hex filename
   3150       0       2    3152     c50 bin/pomodoro.elf

src/spfd54124b.h:96:20: warning: inline function 'SPFD54124B_write_pixel' declared but never defined [enabled by default]
src/spfd54124b.h:95:20: warning: inline function 'SPFD54124B_write_param' declared but never defined [enabled by default]
src/spfd54124b.h:94:20: warning: inline function 'SPFD54124B_write_cmd' declared but never defined [enabled by default]
src/spi.h:22:20: warning: inline function 'spi_write' declared but never defined [enabled by default]
src/spfd54124b.h:96:20: warning: inline function 'SPFD54124B_write_pixel' declared but never defined [enabled by default]
src/spfd54124b.h:95:20: warning: inline function 'SPFD54124B_write_param' declared but never defined [enabled by default]
src/spfd54124b.h:94:20: warning: inline function 'SPFD54124B_write_cmd' declared but never defined [enabled by default]
src/spi.h:22:20: warning: inline function 'spi_write' declared but never defined [enabled by default]
src/pomodoro.c: In function 'main':
src/spfd54124b.h:94:20: warning: inlining failed in call to 'SPFD54124B_write_cmd': function body not available [-Winline]
src/pomodoro.c:29:25: warning: called from here [-Winline]
src/spfd54124b.h:94:20: warning: inlining failed in call to 'SPFD54124B_write_cmd': function body not available [-Winline]
src/pomodoro.c:31:25: warning: called from here [-Winline]
src/spfd54124b.h:94:20: warning: inlining failed in call to 'SPFD54124B_write_cmd': function body not available [-Winline]
src/pomodoro.c:35:25: warning: called from here [-Winline]
src/spfd54124b.h:94:20: warning: inlining failed in call to 'SPFD54124B_write_cmd': function body not available [-Winline]
src/pomodoro.c:36:25: warning: called from here [-Winline]
src/spfd54124b.h:96:20: warning: inlining failed in call to 'SPFD54124B_write_pixel': function body not available [-Winline]
src/pomodoro.c:40:31: warning: called from here [-Winline]
src/spfd54124b.h:94:20: warning: inlining failed in call to 'SPFD54124B_write_cmd': function body not available [-Winline]
src/pomodoro.c:43:25: warning: called from here [-Winline]
```

I'm not sure I understand the different inlining alternatives in c99.

Comment: You have different function names, one is `...123B...` and the other `...124B...`. Fix that and see what problems remain.

Comment: @DanielFischer Oo nice catch

Comment: Well f... me... Why do I allways do that? But fixing it still gives me alot of `src/spfd54124b.h:94:20: warning: inline function 'SPFD54124B_write_cmd' declared but never defined [enabled by default]`

Comment: Does it compile and run?

Comment: It compiles and produces a hex that runs just as expected.

Comment: You misunderstood. You need one non-inline definition.

Comment: @DanielFischer But it says `// a declaration mentioning extern and inline
extern inline int max(int a, int b);

// a definition mentioning inline
inline int max(int a, int b) {
  return a > b ? a : b;
}`
"In either example, the function will be callable from other files."

Comment: @DanielFischer But changing it to the other example sure fixes the problem.... Thanks! No to understand why?

Comment: Ah, right, an explicit `extern` causes an external definition. But apparently, you don't have an inline definition in all translation units and therefore the compiler couldn't actually inline it.

Comment: @DanielFischer Oh, so thats why I got all the "declared but never defined"? Because It was only defined in the one translation unit whereas when I went with inline on the definition and nothing on the declaration I'm saying that this function that I define here should be inlined wherever it's used and the declarations is just a normal declarations so that it can be used everywhere?

Comment: @DanielFischer Put it in an answer and I'll accept straight away since it works now =) Thanks!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You have things exactly the wrong way around from the way you need them.  In the header, you should use:

```
inline void SPFD54124B_write_cmd(uint16_t command)
{
    spi_write(command, CMD_WIDTH);
}
```

In the translation units that include this header, this will create an inline function with external linkage.  In exactly *one* of these translation units you should also place the declaration:

```
extern void SPFD54124B_write_cmd(uint16_t);
```

This (together with the `inline` definition from the header) will create an *external definition* of the function.  The other files that include the header but do not include the `extern` declaration will create an *inline definition* of the function: a definition only available in that translation unit, but that does not forbid an external definition elsewhere.

In total you will have one external definition of the function, and each file that includes the header will also have a non-external definition available; the compiler can use either.  Conceptually there is still just one function called `SPFD54124B_write_cmd` in the complete program - for example if you take the address of the function in multiple translation units you should get the same value.

As an alternative, you can put this in the header:

```
static inline void SPFD54124B_write_cmd(uint16_t command)
{
    spi_write(command, CMD_WIDTH);
}
```

and use no `extern` declaration at all; this will create an inline function with internal linkage in each file that includes the header.  There will be no external definition of the function at all, and conceptually each translation unit that includes the header has its own independent copy of the function.

---

(It should be noted for posterity that GCC's current default mode is "gnu89", which does *not* implement C99 semantics for `inline`)

Comment: Hmmm... I'm using `-std=c99` and `-Winline` and now I have `void SPFD54124B_write_cmd(uint16_t command);` in header spdf54124b.h and a definition `inline void SPFD54124B_write_cmd(uint16_t command) {...}` in spdf54124b.c and then I just include spdf54124b.h from everywhere I need the function. I get no warnings about not inlining. This is proving to be a lot harder than I thought it would =)

Comment: Looking at the assembly I saw that before following this advice the functions was not always inlined, even if i did not get a warning. Having the definition in the header and so on made the binary MUCH larger and the speed MUCH faster, on my MSP430G uc. So this is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 5):

To ensure that a function ACTUALLY can be inlined, it pretty much has to be defined in the header-file.

When you don't do that, most compilers won't actually inline the function.

So my suggestion would be to move the actual function content into the header file:

```
inline void SPFD54124B_write_cmd(uint16_t command)
{
    spi_write(command, CMD_WIDTH);
}
```