# inlining a simple assembly function

Tags: gcc, assembly, x86, inline-assembly, inlining

I (tried to) follow [an old answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17266073/c99-inline-semantics-with-gcc-mspgcc), but I must be doing something wrong: the function is not inlined (it is still called in the disassembly). Here is what I did:

get_regs.h:
    `inline unsigned long __get_esp(void) {`
    `__asm__("movl %esp,%eax");`
    `}`

program.c:
    `...`
    `#include "get_regs.h                 "`
    `...`
    `extern unsigned long __get_esp(void);`
    `...`
    `tmp = __get_esp();`

Compiled as (other options for various reasons):
`gcc -g -fno-stack-protector -mpreferred-stack-boundary=2 program.c`

This follows the second recommendation to include the definition in the header file.

I realize I could use extended assembly and copy the result from `%eax` to `tmp`, but would like to understand to do the inlining. I found some hits on SO, but none seemed to cover my case.

System:
- Ubuntu 12.04
- gcc 4.6.3.
- x86 32 bit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to enable compiler optimization (even the most basic level) for inlining to possibly take place.

By the way, unless you have any special need for a non inlined copy of the function, you can drop the extern re-declaration, and just use the inlined declaration included in the header file.